# R: lubridate::fast_strptime returns different value from base::strptime

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, posixct, strptime

I was trying to convert a date-time characters column in a huge dataframe to POSIXct for further processing. An example of the date-time column is: "Wed Jul 01 00:10:32 UTC 2020".

Due to the large amount of rows (>5 million rows), I was trying the `fastPOSIXct` function in the `fasttime` package to speed it up. My plan was to convert the date-time character to a POSIXlt format and then use the `fastPOSIXct` function to process.

In the process, I found that the `base::strptime` and `lubridate::fast_strptime` returned different outcomes:

```
> base::strptime("Wed Jul 01 00:10:32 UTC 2020", format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y', tz = "UTC")
[1] "2020-07-01 00:10:32 UTC"
```

and

```
> lubridate::fast_strptime("Wed Jul 01 00:10:32 UTC 2020", format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y', tz = "UTC")
[1] NA
```

Why `fast_strptime` returned NAs? Is there any faster way speed up this format conversion process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because fast_strptime function does not accept "a" as appliable format.
If you remove the weekday name argument, it will return the same results.

```
fast_strptime("Jul 01 00:10:32 UTC 2020", format = '%b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y', tz = "UTC")
```

Comment: Thanks, I had an another look in the [lubridate - CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf)  document and it dose say that.